# In R, is there a way to count the number of times a group of 4 values occurred together where the order of the values within the group doesn't matter?

Tags: r, grouping, simulation

Let me explain. I have access to scrubbed data that I'm trying to draw conclusions from. Let's say I'm analyzing blog post tags. For examples, here's a list of tags

```
words <- c("book", "car", "coffee", "lamp",  "phone", "blue", "goat")
```

now for this blog post you must use 4 tags; no more and no less, and you can't repeat tags. After some time we notice that the independent probability that these tags are attached to a blog post are

```
prob <- c(.90, .34, .50, .29, .60, .05, .10)
```

(pretend that the probabilities are valid).

I used the following to simulate 1000 trials of 4 blog tags

```
    results <- data.frame(trial = 1:1000, tag1 = NA, tag2 = NA, tag3 = NA, tag4 = NA)
for (i in 1:nrow(results)) {
    results[i, 2:5] <- sample(words, 4, prob = prob)
}
```

and then used pivot_longer to convert the data to a longer format as so

```
trial move       
<int> <chr>      
1 book    
1 car
1 lamp
1 goat
2 coffee
2 car
2 book     
2 lamp  
3 lamp
3 phone
```

so in trial 1 the simulated blog had tags (book, car, lamp, goat), trial 2 had (coffee, car, book, lamp), etc.

Is there a way in R to count the number of times a group of 4 blog tags occurred, where the order doesn't matter?

i.e. (book, car, lamp, goat) and (car, book, goat, lamp) wouldn't be counted separately.

My goal is to find the simulated distribution of tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my attempt seems to work fine

```
library(tidyverse)

words <- c("book", "car", "coffee", "lamp",  "phone", "blue", "goat")
prob <- c(.90, .34, .50, .29, .60, .05, .10)

results <- data.frame(trial = 1:1000, tag1 = NA, tag2 = NA, tag3 = NA, tag4 = NA)
for (i in 1:nrow(results)) {
  results[i, 2:5] <- sample(words, 4, prob = prob)
}

results_to_token <- results %>% 
  unite("text",-trial,sep = ":") %>% 
  as_tibble()

function_to_use <- function(text_to_use){
  
  str_split(text_to_use,pattern = ":")[[1]] %>% 
    sort() %>% 
    reduce(str_c,sep = " ")
  
  
}

results_to_token_sorted <- results_to_token %>% 
  mutate(sorted_text =  map_chr(text,function_to_use))

results_to_token_sorted %>% 
  count(sorted_text)

# A tibble: 32 x 2
   sorted_text                n
   <chr>                  <int>
 1 blue book car coffee      22
 2 blue book car goat         4
 3 blue book car lamp         5
 4 blue book car phone       14
 5 blue book coffee goat      4
 6 blue book coffee lamp      8
 7 blue book coffee phone    21
 8 blue book goat lamp        3
 9 blue book goat phone       7
10 blue book lamp phone      13
# ... with 22 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

An option is to do compare (`==`) the columns with each corresponding element in that order ('book', 'car', 'lamp', 'goat'), `Reduce` it to a single logical vector with `&` i.e. it will return TRUE only when a single row have the elements in the same order), get the count with `sum` on the logical `vector`

```
sum(Reduce(`&`, Map(`==`, results[-1], c('book', 'car', 'lamp', 'goat'))))
sum(Reduce(`&`, Map(`==`, results[-1], c('coffee', 'car', 'book', 'lamp'))))
```

---

To do this in `base R` for all the groups

```
out <- table(do.call(paste, results[-1]))
```